# NullPointerException ao tentar obter instância do compilador Java

Tags: java, nullpointerexception, compiladores

Seguinte, estou tentando obter uma instância do compilador Java, através do seguinte código:

```
JavaCompiler compiler = ToolProvider.getSystemJavaCompiler();

if (compiler == null) {
    System.out.println("No compiler");
    return;
}
```

O problema é que sempre cai dentro do if, e não consigo entender o porquê disso.

Quero saber o que eu estou fazendo de errado.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Esse problema ocorre quando você executa o código com um JRE e não um JDK. Para resolver, é necessário informar o caminho do JDK na propriedade `java.home`. Uma forma de fazer isso programaticamente é informando diretamente o valor da propriedade no sistema:

```
System.setProperty("java.home", "caminho_do_java");
JavaCompiler compiler = ToolProvider.getSystemJavaCompiler();

if (compiler == null) {
    System.out.println("No compiler");
    return;
}
```

Substitua a string `caminho_do_java` pelo caminho da tua JDK.

Comment: O que é a propriedade `java.home`?

Comment: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/environment/sysprop.html

Comment: Seria interessante adicionar o link na resposta, direcionada do "java.home", assim, caso alguem que leia e não entenda, basta clicar no link para conferir.

Comment: @GiulianaBezerra Já tinha tentado fazer isso, mas obtive o seguinte erro java.lang.InternalError: java.io.FileNotFoundException: C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_101\lib\currency.data (O sistema não pode encontrar o arquivo especificado)

Comment: @GiulianaBezerra Consegui resolver do jeito que você falou, mas depois de setar a propriedade `java.home` para o jdk e obter a instância do compilador, setei de volta para a jre, o que resolveu o problema que eu citei acima. Muito obrigado!